# iOS 11 - UIDocumentBrowserViewController create new document with Template Chooser, how to set up?

Tags: ios, ios11

I have an existing Objective-C document-based app where I've replaced my previous file manager with the new UIDocumentBrowserViewController, and everything works -- except I'm absolutely stumped on how to create a new document with a template chooser.  According to the WWDC 2017 video "Building Great Document-based Apps in iOS 11" you should approach it like this:

```
func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didRequestDocumentCreationWithHandler importHandler: @escaping (URL?, UIDocumentBrowserViewController.ImportMode) -> Swift.Void) 
{  
presentTemplateChooser(completion: {templateURL, canceled) in  
    if let templateURL = templateURL  
    {  
      importHandler(templateURL, .copy)  
    }  
    else  
    {  
      importHandler(nil, .none)  
    }  
}
```

What does make sense to me is presenting the Template Chooser, but what doesn't make sense to me is I have a "Done" and "Cancel" button on the template chooser; but how do I know when the user taps "Done" or "Cancel" on the Template Chooser and pass that into the delegate function?  Anybody know how to pull this off in (preferably) Objective-C?  (But Swift is fine too, just trying to get an idea of how this process works)  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for Objective-C preferably but this is an example of Swift's optionals pattern. If your presentTemplateChooser method calls its completion closure without a templateURL (i.e. it is nil), then unwrapping templateURL will fail (if let templateURL = templateURL will return false).

If you want to know if the user explicitly pressed cancel, you can do that like this:

Create the cancel action like this:

```
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { _ in
        completion(nil, true)
    }
```

The method in your question should then be:

```
func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didRequestDocumentCreationWithHandler importHandler: @escaping (URL?, UIDocumentBrowserViewController.ImportMode) -> Swift.Void) 
{  
presentTemplateChooser(completion: {templateURL, canceled) in  
    if canceled {
      print("User canceled")
    }
    if let templateURL = templateURL  
    {  
      importHandler(templateURL, .copy)  
    }  
    else  
    {  
      importHandler(nil, .none)  
    }  
}
```

You can do all of this in Objective-C. You would just need to check for nil instead of unwrapping for templateURL. (i.e. if templateURL != nil instead of if templateURL = templateURL).

Comment: Hmm, does this actually work as intended? I am trying something similar (in Objective-C though), but the completion handler of the -documentBrowser:didRequestDocumentCreationWithHandler: instance method is called as soon as the template choosing view has been displayed ("presented"), not after the user has made a choice in it and it has been dismissed. What am I missing?